# how to modify a variable value in a Python module using inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I have a class A with many methods. There is one particular method that is referring to an external variable from the module imported. I don't have control of the module. In order to work around the problem I have created a class B that inherits from class A and modified the method by removing the reference to this external value. However, this a large method that might change. Is there a way to inherit the entire class but only modify the external value from the module?

```py
external_value = 5
class A():

    def add(self, b, c):            
        print(external_value)
        print(b+c)
        #100s of lines of code

class B(A):

    def add(self, b,c):
        print(b+c)
        #100s of lines of code


a1 = A()
a1.add(3,5)

b1 = B()
b1.add(3,5)
```

Comment: Depending on how the value is used, you could use [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) as a context manager inside `B`'s add, which apart from that just calls `super().add(b, c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) for this:

#### external_module.py:

```
external_value = 5

class A:
    def add(self, a, b):
        print(external_value)
        print(a + b)
```

#### your_module.py:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from external_module import A

class B(A):
    def add(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with patch("external_module.external_value", 99):
            return super().add(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you now instantiate `B` and call `add`, this happens:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.add(1, 2)
99
3
```